# Youtube API + Android + Webview

Tags: android, mobile, video, youtube-api

I've downloaded the Youtube api sample files and edited the sample apps so that only the `standalonePlayerDemoActivity` can be used (Just for this prototype & testing).

I tested it and it all works fine.

I then added a `webview` and a `button`. I was trying to replace the `button` from the sample code with a html button I created.

However I am unable to get it working.

I was wondering if anyone knew of an example of the Youtube api working with a html button or if anyone could build a simple tutorial.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For Android Youtube Player, you can check the code on [YouTube Direct Lite for Android.](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android)

Comment: The link you suggested does not show a example of what I asked for. The code is described as follows, "The code is a reference implementation for an Android OS application that captures video, uploads it to YouTube, and submits the video to a YouTube Direct Lite instance."